# How do I store a 2d Array to a text file (vb)

Tags: arrays, vb.net, file, text, output

I want to store the array (OutputArray) to a text file, with the columns seperated be commas, and the rows by line breaks, this is the code now:

```
    Dim myFile As System.IO.StreamWriter
    myFile = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(“file.txt”, False)
    For i = 0 To lineCount
        For j = 0 To 9
            System.IO.File.AppendText("file.txt", outputarray(i, j) & ",")
        Next
    Next
    myFile.Close()
```

but an error is thrown out :
Error   BC30057 Too many arguments to 'Public Shared Overloads Function AppendText(path As String) As StreamWriter'.

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: i've just edited the question, sorry

Comment: OK. Then look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.file.appendtext(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: to help - in your second for loop Using sw As StreamWriter = File.AppendText(path) - then add stuff

Comment: @codeMonger123 Better to put the `Using` around the loops so you don't end up creating, opening, closing and disposing the stream `9 * lineCount` times

Comment: Yes - I believe that you are correct.